# Inequality operators of both directions aligned vertically in one expression?

Tags: math-mode, comparison

I would like to put inequality operators of both directions, i.e. `<` and `>`, aligned vertically in one expression. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You should familiarize yourself with the [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) utility, which lets you "draw" (on a computer screen) the symbol of interest; the program will provide one or more suggestions for possible LaTeX macros that create symbols that might look similar to what you've drawn.

Comment: @Mico I am afraid that the linked entry is too general to a beginner, so I do not treat this question as a duplicate.

Comment: They should be aligned vertically already. Could you explain what exactly you're after?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke  - Hmmm, I would have said that the linked posting -- and especially the most-upvoted answer -- is perfect for LaTeX beginners. :-)

Comment: @Mico Oh, Detexify is really nice. Writing down `+` I've obtained (only) `\perp`, `\dagger`, `\dag`, `\bot` and `\cross`. And I am still afraid, that the question may be about multiline expressions...

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that you have in mind one of the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\gtrless\text{ or }\lessgtr
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Przemyslaw, thank you so much. My problem is resolved!